# Getting information from a microservice in a event drivent architecture

Tags: events, apache-kafka, microservices, event-driven

I have some experience doing REST microservices architecture, but now I want ot start using kafka as a message provider in my Event drivenr architecture.

I have an issue understanding how the communication works between microservices.

Lets say I have two microservices one that deals with users and another one with messages between users.

Users can be created, and then users can send another users messages, and I am planning to do them with topics and then store them in a MongoDB.

How do I retrieve this messages in a event driven architecture?

EDIT: The example is quite simple is just for educational purpose and to practice with Apache-Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, let's call user messages instead as posts.

One possible architecture is all users create post objects, which are sent to a Kafka topic that contains information such as timestamp, sender and sendee, rather than directly as a database insert.

Out of Kafka, you write some consumer process(es) to poll all messages from the topic, then insert to Mongo (and possibly also a search engine or machine learning / text categorization model).

On another user account, they (periodically) query the database for all posts sent to them, as Kafka is not indexable by a user account and one topic per user is not a scalable design pattern.

The gist is that users aren't directly retrieving posts from Kafka, but you've buffered messages in Kafka so they can be forked into different models so that you can decouple your application from a Mongo dependency (except for having a search feature)

From events, you can separate out "posts-new", "posts-edit", and "posts-deletes" as separate topics. For more context about designing this, you can look into Event Storming

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now my idea was to have an API that communicates with the user. Such as create users and send messages. When sending a message how would be the process to identify the user is in the database befire creating the event? Do you make a nested event?

Comment: You can put a Kafka producer behind a REST API, sure. If I understand the question, you would probably want a session token based on a separate login event before being able to send any messages. The login flow is responsible for user existence, not the messaging flow